# Why python dictionary only update the last value appended?

Tags: python

I have a mongodb database and I retrieve some information from it. And I try to append it to a python dictionary using a for loop, but it only appends the last row.

here's my code:

```
import pymongo
import datetime

# @app.route("/bemployees", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def retrieve_all_documents():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "<url-removed>"
    )

    

    # database
    db = client.cdap

    # collection (table)
    collection = db.predicted_values

    cursor = collection.find({})

    documents_ = {}

    for document in cursor:
        documents_.update(document)
        print(document) # prints all the records

    print(documents_) # only prints the last record

    return documents_
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: *Append*? That's not how dictionaries work. It sounds like you want a list.

Comment: I don't understand. I assume that each `document` is a dict that has all the same keys. And you expect to store all of these in a single dict, and it should look like - what, exactly? You do understand that a `dict` can  only store a given key once? That is its *purpose*; by looking up a key in the dict, you unambiguously get the associated value.

Comment: `mongodb` retrieves a dictionary (a javascript object), and I want to store it in a python variable that is suitable for front-end reactjs application so I can map that object.

Comment: `dict.update()` overwrites values in keys if updated keys are the same as the existing ones. A python dictionary can only have unique keys. What you want, I'm assuming, is to have `documents_` to be of type `list`, and `append()` incoming documents to that list.

Comment: @KirillG okay. then how should my reactjs front-end look like after getting the response from this python?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each document is a dict that has all the same keys. I think you need a list to store.

```
documents_ = []
for i in cursor:
   dic = {}
   dic.update(i)
   documents_.append(dic)
print(documents_)
```

> Please share your response data in the question that will helpful for answer this question thank you

Comment: Hi, now I get this error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.`

Comment: I want to access this data from my reactjs front-end. can you provide a small example for that as well?